# Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code here:

```
interface MyClass {
    fun main() {
        File(TentDatabase.getPathRepository(context)).walkBottomUp()
                .filter { it.isFile }
                .forEach { parseFiles(it) } //I think here is the problem
    }

      fun parseFiles(file: File) {
             val extension = file.path.substringAfterLast('.', "")
             Log.i("DB", "name - $extension")
      } 
}
```

WhenI  try to run this code I get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void org.secfirst.umbrella.data.internal.TentDao.parseFiles(java.io.File)"
```

How do I pass a function as a parameter? I just want to execute parseFiles(file) for each iteration.

Comment: What is your Kotlin dependency in your build.gradle?

Comment: Hey @EpicPandaForce I have these dependencies : implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.41"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.41"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question:

> How do I pass a function as a parameter? I just want to execute parseFiles(file) for each iteration

You can simply replace:

```
.forEach { parseFiles(it) }
```

with:

```
.forEach(::parseFiles)
```

Which represents a reference, you are passing the name of the function that can take care of the type of parameter the `forEach` will produce.

---

But the exception that you're getting it's related to something else. I think it's related to the version of your final bytecode. I tested your code on an environment using

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

and

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

so in java 8 you have access to `default` methods on interfaces, Kotlin has this by default but if you are targeting Java 7 probably you don't have access to this. That's my guess.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching:

For me, this was caused by a mixture of Java and Kotlin classes.

Try converting some classes related to the method and caller, including the implementation of the interface/abstract class and its superclasses to Kotlin.

Implemented interface methods are somehow interpreted as abstract methods in java; instead of default ones.